# How to download a signed document, one document at a time from an agreement in Adobe Sign using REST API?

Tags: adobe-sign

Once a document is signed and I want to download the signed document stream, Adobe Sign API currently offers two endpoints but with some limitations. How to download a signed document, one document at a time from an agreement?

a.  `GET /agreements/{agreementId}/documents/{documentId}` – This endpoint allows to download a document present in an agreement but the stream that is downloaded is not up to date and does not have a signature on it.

b.  `GET /agreements/{agreementId}/combinedDocument` - This endpoint allows to download all the documents present in an agreement into one combined pdf, but it does not support our business logic of wanting to download individual signed document in an agreement with multiple documents.